# Verify Actual Text Value vs Expected for many fields - Selenium

Tags: selenium, field, verify

How would one confirm that on a page the following text fields exists:

Name
Surname
DoB
ActionNumber
PageNumber

they all have ID attributes of the field name.

other than using (Pysdo code)

```
String ActualSurnameText = driver.findElement(By.ID("Surname")).getText();
If ActualSurnameText = ExpectedSurnameText then Pass else fail
```

is their a smater more efficient way

**EDIT**

Probably should mention that each label is nested in a div so the structure goes like

```
<div class="top">
 <div class="middle">
  <div class="lower">
   <label class="lable">
   <div class="bottom">
   <input>
```

***EDIT***
So currently i've declaired an array

```
String[] ExpectedFieldNAme = new String[4]
ExpectedFieldName[0] = "Name";
ExpectedFieldName[0] = "Surname";
ExpectedFieldName[0] = "DoB";
ExpectedFieldName[0] = "ActionNumber";
ExpectedFieldName[0] = "PAgeNumber";

<need to code for a loop that pysdo goes>
For (int i = 0, i < div.size(); i++){
does div.label.text = anything value in ExpectedFieldName;
print yes it does}
print no it doesnt
repeat untill all the div labels have been identified`
```

Comment: If the field doesn't exist, findElement throws an exception and your test fails. You do not need to do a `getText` and verify it.

Comment: @KDM What if the element exists but doesn't contain the text you expect? That's why you need to do a `.getText()` and verify the expected text is contained.

Comment: @JeffC I think the requirement is to look for the presence of element..

Comment: @KDM if you look at his pseudo code, he's trying to validate that the expected text is on the page. He also states that each one has an ID... if they each have an ID and he's only trying to validate that they exist, there would be no need to validate text at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of libraries that already exist to do validations like this. I would suggest that you read up on several and try a few and find one that you like. TestNG, JUnit are a couple popular ones but there are others.

With TestNG there are many validation functions. For example, to compare two strings

```
assertEquals("Verify name", ExpectedSurnameText, ActualSurnameText);
```

---

I understand what you are trying to do and it does seem "better", less code, to do it that way but it's not better. A better validation is to look for the expected text where you expect it to prevent false positives. A simple example might help. Let's say you are searching for the text, "DOB", that is a field label. You search the entire text of the page. What if you have instructions elsewhere on the page that state, "Please enter your DOB." One day the field label text is gone but your script still finds "DOB" on the page because it matched the instruction text instead of the label. That is the danger of not looking for the expected text in the expected place. What you want to do is something like this

```
// assume expected text variables are defined earlier in the test

// Name
String ActualName = driver.findElement(By.id("Name")).getText().trim();
assertEquals("Verify name", ExpectedName, ActualName);

// Surname
String ActualSurname = driver.findElement(By.id("Surname")).getText().trim();
assertEquals("Verify Surname", ExpectedSurname, ActualSurname);
```

That's only 2 lines of code per field, you aren't going to get any better than that with an array because you still have to do the validation (1 line) and you have to load the array (1+ lines)

Comment: What i would like to acheive is to; instead of having 
`assertEquals("Verify name", ExpectedSurnameText, ActualSurnameText)`; 20 times for each label on the page; to have a one FOR LOOP (?) to say
`For (each label in DIV (Class = Lower) ) does my expectedtext match the ActualText`

So some type of array to hold the expected maybe - but this is all new to me...

Comment: I don't understand your statement.

Comment: Okay lets try it this way: sort of what @Rupesh Shinde said about having many labels on a page, you wouldnt want to manaully code for each labl, but rather have a loop to say go to each label on the page and does it match any of the values ive said in my array?

Comment: I understand what you are asking but if you do a loop that iterates through an array, you still have to load the array. I think it will be less confusing if you just do one validation per field. Remember you will likely want a label for each validation, Verify name, surname, dob, etc. That's going to get messy if you have to load different arrays for label, expected, and actual values. It will also be more work if you add another value later.

Answer (score -1):

Answering you Question *How would one confirm that on a page the following text fields exists:*
Below command will return **True** only if the your page contains your Desired Text.

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Text-you-are-Looking-for"));
```

The execution will stop if it returns **False**. Suggested to use it wisely.

Comment: @Jeff My answer more precisely says about a page and not a particular web-element. Please check the First Line of the Question. And getText() works when you know that  specific web-element, What if you page contains more then 100 WebElements?  Will you use GetText() for all 100 elements ?

Comment: ...and he states, "they all have ID attributes of the field name" so no, you wouldn't search the whole web page for the text, you would find the element by ID and then do `.getText()`. He also didn't say there were 100 elements, he listed 5 that he needed. In any decent sized web page, there are WAY more than 100 elements... that's why there are all the different find methods available to narrow the search quickly.